# cups-pdf via cups-lpd creates PDF files with no content but printer config

Tags: pdf, cups, lp

I'm using cups-pdf to print via lpd (Port 515)
That's working so far, but all pdf-files are created with its content of the printer configuration. The PDF file includes following:

```
Media Limits: 0.00 x 0.00 to 8.26 x 11.69 inches
Job ID: PDFPrinter003-197
Driver: CUPS-PDF.PPD
Driver Version: 1.1
Description: SAP2PDF
Driver Version: SAP2PDF
Make and Model: Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (no options)
Printer: PDFPrinter003
Created at: Tue Jun 27 12:42:12 2017
Printed at: Tue Jun 27 12:42:12 2017
```

I can't find anything interesting in the log files.
In /var/log/cups/cups-pdf-PDFPrinter003_log is everything fine about the PDF Creation.

In /var/log/cups/error_log is the following:

```
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:11 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:11 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:11 +0200] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:38 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:38 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:38 +0200] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:46 +0200] Unexpected 'document-format' operation attribute in a Create-Job request.
W [27/Jun/2017:13:00:46 +0200] Unexpected 'document-name' operation attribute in a Create-Job request.
```

My xinetd.conf part for lpd-printing is the following:

```
service printer
    {
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        wait = no
        user = lp
        server = /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-lpd
    }
```

Please ask if something is missing.

Do you have an idea?

Greetz Eldo.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

it was a "feature" in lpd. By default, lpd prints a "banner" and creates 2 spool-files. The first spool file has been printet, but it's only the banner and the second file was ignored by cups-pdf.

I had to disable the banner in the xinetd.conf

```
server_args = -o document-format=application/octet-stream -o job-sheets=none,none
```

That solved my problem.